# What part of the C language handles type checking?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Does a language feature allow the compiler to check the type of a variable in memory, or is type checking based only on the keyword used for the variable type?

For example:

```
unsigned short n = 3;
         int *p = &n;
```

Both int and short use 4 bytes in memory, but the compiler cannot implicitly convert from a short * to an int *. How does the compiler know that **n** isn't a valid address for **p** in this case?

Comment: It doesn't and it doesn't and it doesn't.

Comment: Why wouldn't the compiler be able to know that? It could have a mapping from variable name to type for the scope.

Comment: That is the basic duty of the parser, the part of the compiler that interprets statements and generates code.  Variables like n and p appear in the symbol table, it describes their type, size and address.  The part of the parser that handles assignment checks if the right-hand expression type matches the left-hand lvalue type.  The mismatching types and lack of an implicit conversion gets it to generate an error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a language feature allow the compiler to check the type of a variable in memory, or is type checking based only on the keyword used for the variable type?

This is a very confused question. The compiler is the thing that implements the language. Therefore a language feature might *require* the compiler to do certain things (in order to make the feature work), but it doesn't *allow* the compiler to do things.

A "variable in memory" is a run-time concept. The compiler is only involved at compile time: It translates code in some language (the source language) into another language (the target language, typically assembler code / machine code). It emits instructions that (when executed) reserve memory and use this memory to store values. But at run-time, when the program is actually executed, the compiler is no longer part of the picture, so it can't check anything.

In C, types are checked at compile time. The compiler knows the types of literals (e.g. `42` is an `int` and `"hello"` is a `char [6]`), and it knows the type of everything you declare (because it has to parse the declarations), including variables. Type checking and type conversion rules are unrelated to the sizes of types.

For example:

```
short int a = 42;
double b = a;  // OK, even though commonly sizeof a == 2 and sizeof b == 8
```

On the other hand:

```
signed char c;
char *p = &c;  // error, even though commonly char and signed char have the same
               // size, representation, and range of possible values
```

It is perfectly possible to type-check C without actually generating any code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm new to thinking of lower level programming concepts. Your explanation clarified and solidified a few things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Every expression has a type, ultimately derived from the types of the variables and literals that appear in it.  The type of `&n` is `unsigned short*`, and that cannot be used to initialize a variable of type `int*`.  This has nothing to do with examining memory, so it works regardless of context other than the variable types.